# How to generate files from a list with dictionaries, each dictionary into a separate file according to the template?

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template, bind9

The task is to generate dns zone files, each zone in a separate file.

Is it possible to somehow complete this task with modules, or will I have to write something of my own?

## I'm stuck here:

### List with dict:

```
bind_zones:
  - name: "example.com"
    file: "example.com.zone"
    ttl: 3600
    zone_serial: "{{ bind_zone_serial }}"
    zone_refresh: 3600
    zone_retry: 7200
    zone_expire: 3600000
    zone_minimum: 3600
    records:
      - name: "@"
        ttl: 3800
        class: IN
        type: NS
        data: ns1
      - name: "@"
        type: A
        data: "192.0.2.1"
      - name: "@"
        type: AAAA
        data: "2001:db8::1"
      - name: "www"
        type: CNAME
        data: "@"
```

### Task:

```
- name: "Generate zone files"
  template:
    src: zones.conf.j2
    dest: "{{ item.file }}"
    owner: root
    group: "{{ bind_group }}"
    mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
    validate: '{{ bind_bin_path }}named-checkconf -z -j %s'
  loop: "{{ bind_zones }}"
```

### Template (but of course the template is broken, just an attempt for example):

```
{{ ansible_managed | comment(decoration='; ') }}
$ORIGIN {{ bind_zones['name'] }}.
$TTL {{ bind_zones['ttl'] }}
$INCLUDE {{ bind_zones_path }}{{ bind_share_properties_zone_filename }}

{% for record in bind_zones['name']['records'] %}
{{ record['name'] }}                {% if record['ttl'] is defined %}{{ record['ttl'] }}{% endif %} {% if record['class'] is defined %}{{ record['class'] }}{% endif %} {{ record['type'] }}        {{ record['data'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

It should work out, each domain in a separate file.

Comment: FWIW. See [ansible-freebsd-dns](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-dns). Many parts of the role, e.g. templates, might be reusable in other systems, I think.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is necessary to **use the service variable** `item`, this is enough. Thanks @vladimir-botka !